# How do I cast ddmonyyyy date format in hive

Tags: hive

How convertion of **ddmonyyyy** date format in hive works?
I tried this way

```
select (from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mb_date,’ddMMyyyy’))) from tbl1;
```

But there is still issue in casting.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(mb_date,'ddMMMyyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from tbl1 limit 10; I tried this and it worked for me.

Comment: @Patrik Khanal, if you found a solution you should provide it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @DaniilT. Thanks for reminding , done already

Answer (score 0):

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(mb_date,'ddMMMyyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from tbl1 limit 10; I tried this and it worked for me.